# How to capture result from cat in unix, for server monitoring

Tags: unix, monitoring

Hi I need to create a server monitoring, where I need to store the memory in use, cpu utilization by processes and overall cpu utilization.
I wrote the below script using top command

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo " " > top.txt

top -b -d 1 > top.txt

var =20

MEM = "$(cat top.txt |grep Memory | cut -c 8-12)"

JAV = $(cat top.txt |grep java | cut -c 55-60)

SSH = $(cat top.txt |grep ssh | cut -c 55-60)

mailing_list="xxxxxx@yyyy.co.in"

subject_line="monitring"

if [ $mem -gt $var || $ jav -gt "10" || $ssh -gt "10"] ;then
echo $mem
echo $jav
echo $ssh

echo "there is some problem"| mailx -b "${mailing_list}" -s "${subject_line}" " "
   fi


exit 0
```

When i execute thisa script I recieve a waring that mem jav not found.

Please help me with this

My task is to create a monitoring script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the output of- `cat top.txt |grep java | cut -c 55-60`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have spaces around `=` in your variable assignments.  Remove those.  That is what causes those `MEM: command not found` errors.
- You say:

> if [ $mem -gt $var || $ jav -gt "10" || $ssh -gt "10"] ;then

There are multiple problems with this.  Say:

```
if [[ $mem -gt $var || $jav -gt "10" || $ssh -gt "10" ]]; then
```

- You also seem to be mixing cases.  Variable names are **case-sensitive**.

Comment: I need one more help : can you please help me ho can I capture the last line from the output of sar command in unix.

Comment: @user3045919 Try `value=$(sar ... | tail -1)`

Comment: Thanks buddy.. It works for me. With your help I just wrote the first script of my life,